# Why has my live Preview VSC extension logo disappeared?

Tags: visual-studio-code, live-preview

I’m very new to coding and have tried to search previous questions but to no avail.

My ‘live preview’ extension was working fine in Visual Studio Code - I just clicked a little icon on the right and saw a HTML preview of my site.

Suddenly it has disappeared and I can’t work out how to get it back.

I have tried:
Restarting windows and VSC
Re-opening the folder I’m working on
Disabling all and enabling all extensions and restarting
Disabling / removing the extension and re-downloading
Trying a different preview extension

And nothing is working! Please help?

Also please explain like I’m an idiot if it’s anything technical.

Comment: right click on the status bar. check the permission to show the icon.

Comment: The options I have when I RC the status bar are: Worksoace trust / problems / editor selection / editor indentation / editor encoding / editor end of line / editor language / feedback / notifications  - I can’t see anything else and they are all checked currently?

Comment: This is now solved. I uninstalled VSC. Then created a new file which it recognised as html (which it wasn’t before despite same code) and then the icon came back!

Answer (score 5):

i found the problem . its language selection on buttom right corner on vs code and you need to change it to HTML.